# Pytest hook can't find fixture

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I'm trying to generate a screenshot for the allure report using the `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook but get stuck because 'if' statement=false in this block of code:

```
 if 'setup' in item.fixturenames:
                        web_driver = item.funcargs['setup']
                    else:
                        print('Fail to take screenshot.No setup fixture found')
```

Here is conftest.py:

```
  @pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def get_webdriver(get_edge_options):
    options = get_edge_options
    print("Current working dir : %s" % os.getcwd())
    s = Service('D:\mmanager\msedgedriver.exe')
    driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s, options=options)
    # driver.delete_all_cookies()
    return driver


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')  # function means run each test in new browser session
def setup(request, get_webdriver):
    driver = get_webdriver
    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver
    driver.get(FCC_HOME)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()


# Shared Given Steps

@given('the MM3-0 login page is displayed', target_fixture='MM_Login_page')
def MM_Login_page(setup):
    pass



@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    if (rep.when == 'call' or rep.when == 'setup') and (rep.failed or rep.skipped):
        try:
            if 'setup' in item.fixturenames:
                web_driver = item.funcargs['setup']
            else:
                print('Fail to take screenshot.No setup fixture found')
                return
            allure.attach(
                web_driver.get_screenshot_as_png(),
                name='!! Screenshot Captured !!',
                attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Fail to take screen-shot: {}'.format(e))
```

Comment: So did you add `setup` to the test function? Or maybe you want to make it an `autouse` fixture?

Comment: I added 'setup' as argument to the test function:  
`def Login(setup, username: str, password):  
    # LoginHelper(setup).login_to_app(username, password)  

    po = PurchaseOrdersHelper(setup)  
    po.open_po_page()`

Comment: `Login` is your test function? Have you customized the test name lookup?

Comment: Yes, `Login` is test function, it step-definition for BDD cases